# CSS Customization for slider?

Tags: css

I am using this slider: http://jqueryui.com/slider/ but I want to use my own custom slider button, can you check the code for me and say me which class should I edit to make a custom button.

Comment: Look for `.ui-slider-handle`.

Comment: It changed the size of width and height, but It didnt change the background Image I wanted it to be.

Comment: simply use chrome or firefox with firebug addon or any IE then hit F12 in developer tools you can select page elements and see their attributes like class or ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery-ui.css

line no 822 has a class (ui-state-default) for slider handle.

You can edit it there or you can attach you own css for class .ui-state-default to overwrite it.